# EF Code First cascade delete doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework

I have 4 tables:

User table

```
public enum SEX { Male, Female }

public abstract class User
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public SEX Sex { get; set; }
}
```

Doctor table inherites from User

```
[Table("Doctor")]
public class Doctor : User
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public string CabinetNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Treat> Treats { get; set; }
}
```

Patient table inherites from User

```
[Table("Patient")]
public class Patient : User
{
    public int InsuranceNumber { get; set; }
    public int CardNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Treat> Treats { get; set; }
}

public class Treat
{
    public int TreatId { get; set; }

    public int DoctorUserId { get; set; }
    public int PatientUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class HospitalContext: DbContext
    {
        public HospitalContext() : base("DBConnectionString") {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<HospitalContext>());
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Treat>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Doctor)
                .WithMany( x => x.Treats)
                .HasForeignKey( x => x.DoctorUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Treat>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Patient)
                .WithMany( x => x.Treats)
                .HasForeignKey( x => x.PatientUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Treat> Treats { get; set; }
    }
```

I have found much answers here but no one from them works. I have spend a few hours trying to make it work. I know that Entity Framework must enable cascade delete when there is one-to-many relation, but it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't apply cascade deletion with TPT (Table Per Type) inheritance. You can solve this with Code Fist migrations:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Treats",
    c => new
    {
        TreatId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        DoctorUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        PatientUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.TreatId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Doctor", t => t.DoctorUserId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Patient", t => t.PatientUserId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.DoctorUserId)
    .Index(t => t.PatientUserId);
```

The important part is `cascadeDelete: true`. You have to manually add it after migration code generation. After that you will have cascade deletion in your database:

```
FOREIGN KEY ([DoctorUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Doctor] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ([PatientUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Patient] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It doesn't work. I have created a new project to test another time from the ground up and create step by step codefirst database with migrations and all works fine until I created Inheritance User <- Doctor. User <- Patient of TPT Inheritance strategy. In this inheritance strategy it doesn't work. But I have tried to make it in TPC strategy and it works fine.

Comment: @Vorotnyak_Nazar Updated answer.

Comment: Really? Do you know why it doesn't work? So basic and when you use it, it gives you no exception!